# DownloadString not getting executed

Tags: c#, webclient

I am new to C#.Net programming and facing a problem. When I am calling getLocation function, I always get "location" empty. I know I am doing things in wrong manner. But It would be great if someone can help me to do it in correct way. I want getLocation function to return location value. So, it should return only when wc.downloadString gets executed before returning location value.

```
public String getLocation()
{
    RetrieveFormatedAddress(latitude, longitutde);
    location = returnVal;
    return location;
}

static void RetrieveFormatedAddress(string lat, string lng)
{
    string requestUri = string.Format(baseUri, lat, lng);

    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
        wc.DownloadString(new Uri(requestUri));
        //wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(requestUri));
    }
}

private static void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var xmlElm = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

    var status = (from elm in xmlElm.Descendants()
                  where elm.Name == "status"
                  select elm).FirstOrDefault();
    if (status.Value.ToLower() == "ok")
    {
        var res = (from elm in xmlElm.Descendants()
                   where elm.Name == "formatted_address"
                   select elm).FirstOrDefault();
        returnVal = res.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        returnVal = "No Address Found";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public String getLocation()
{
    return RetrieveFormatedAddress(latitude, longitutde);
}

static string RetrieveFormatedAddress(string lat, string lng)
{
    string requestUri = string.Format(baseUri, lat, lng);

    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        var result = wc.DownloadString(new Uri(requestUri));
        var xmlElm = XElement.Parse(result);

        var status = (from elm in xmlElm.Descendants()
              where elm.Name == "status"
              select elm).FirstOrDefault();
        if (status.Value.ToLower() == "ok")
        {
        var res = (from elm in xmlElm.Descendants()
               where elm.Name == "formatted_address"
               select elm).FirstOrDefault();
            return res.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            return "No Address Found";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked.
If I use DownloadStringAsync, was that method correct ?
How can I make sure that I have correct value in location in that case. Initially I was trying DownloadStringAsync but it wasn't working

Comment: The reason your async version didn't work is because getLocation was returning before wc_DownloadStringCompleted was getting called.  I'm not sure what version of .NET you're using, but you may want to look into the async and await keywords for this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

The `DownloadString()` method is a synchronous version of `DownloadStringAsync()` method. It returns data downloaded from the server as a string. In your code, you're not reading this value anywhere. Try `var data = wc.DownloadString(new Uri(requestUri));` to get the data.